# in my c# app the date like 2019/01/25 after printing by report viewer be like 1/25/2018

Tags: c#, .net, date, printing, reportviewer

i installed my c# app in a pc that had a windows 7 system English vesion, the date system format is yyyy-MM-dd in my app i saw it in the same format yyyy-MM-dd when i want to print a document using my app in the reportviewer of c# i saw the date in the same format yyyy-MM-dd but when i print it or save it as a PDF the date format be like M/d/yyyy for example:
2019-01-25 after printing be like 1/25/2019.
i need to print my document in the same date format of the system yyyy/MM/dd so i hope that someone give me the solution and thank you.

Comment: This question is very vague but more or less when you format date time you need to pass a format that specifies how it should be represented. If you don't do that it will use the culture settings from OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the DateTime output to a certain format, you must specify that format.  If you do not specify the format the DateTime will use the CultureInfo of the system.

In your case try:

```
var date = new DateTime();
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```